# Get Exact Class Name That Starts With Certain Characters

Tags: jquery, css, startswith

Objective:
I'm trying to retrieve the value: "bg-green" or "bg-blue" but I won't necessarily know it is "green" or "blue" when the DOM is loaded. I also won't know the number of classes each div will have or where "bg-[color]" will fall in the lineup of classes for that div. I should emphasize that I know how to find the div with a class that begins with "bg-" but not necessarily how to retrieve the actual class name once it's found.

```
<div class="bg-green classUno anotherClass littleBox">
 This is my green Div
</div>

<div class="classUno anotherClass bg-blue littleBox">
 This is my blue Div
</div>
```

Comment: If the class order is always going to be different, you could add a data-color="" property to the div to make it easier to extract.

Comment: Probably you are looking for "classList", <found div>.classList

Answer (score 1):

Use the selector to grab the element, and then grab it's class, then split on the constant, and take what comes after.

```
var $cn = $('[class^=bg]').prop('class');
console.log($cn.split('bg-')[1]);
```

[here's your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ussm63we/)

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy! Though I should have been more explicit in my question. There is more than 1 class and I won't exactly know where the "bg-[color]" class will be in the line of classes for that div.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to extract the colour information by adding a data attribute to your divs.

```
<div class="classUno anotherClass bg-blue littleBox" data-color="blue">
   This is my blue Div
</div>
```

You could then check if a data-color attribute exists, and if so extract it like so:

```
if ($('div').data('color') !== 'undefined') {
   var color = $('div').attr('data-color');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(element.classList.contains("myStyle")){
  // works for one or more class names
  // if "myStyle" is one of the classnames present
  // then run your code here
  alert("This elment has the class myStyle!");
}
```